# How to make something execute for a certain amount of time

Tags: java, oop, time

This is a space invaders game that I am making. this piece of code processes the collision with an item and the shooter. at the start of the game the shooter can shoot a max of 3, when the shooter collects an item it can shoot a max of 10 for 3 seconds. I have tried to use a for loop but it never reverts back to max size of 3

without for loop

```
//items vs shooter
var removeItems = new ArrayList<>();
for(var blocks: shooter.getComponents()){
    for(var i: items){
        if(blocks.collideWith(i)){
            removeItems.add(i);
            shooter.setMAX_BULLETS(10);
        }
    }
}
items.removeAll(removeItems);
```

with for loop

```
var removeItems = new ArrayList<>();
for(var blocks: shooter.getComponents()){
    for(var i: items){
        if(blocks.collideWith(i)){
            removeItems.add(i);
            for(int j =0; j<3;j++){
                shooter.setMAX_BULLETS(10);
            }
        }
    }
}
items.removeAll(removeItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the max bullets back to 3 anywhere. add `shooter.setMAX_BULLETS(3)` after the for loop.

```
for(int j =0; j<3;j++){
    shooter.setMAX_BULLETS(10);
}
shooter.setMAX_BULLETS(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question

```
Thread shootThread = new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            shooter.setMAX_BULLETS(10);
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(3000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            shooter.setMAX_BULLETS(3);
                        }
                    };
                    shootThread.start();
```